# Sorting Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors in Julia 1.0

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

This question isn't so much a need for a solution but rather to ask if my approach is natural to the Julia language (Julianic?), if not what would be a more natural implementation:

```
@doc """
function sorteigen!(evals::Array{Number,1},evecs::Array{Number,2})

Sort the eigenvalues and vectors.
"""
function sorteigen!(evals::Array{Number,1},evecs::Array{Number,2})
n=size(evecs)[1];

#Shallow copy and force local scope
local sortedevals = copy(evals);
local sortedevecs = copy(evecs);

#Sort eigenvalue Array{Number,1}
sortedindex = sortperm(evals);
evals[:] = sortedevals[sortedindex];

#Sort eigenvectors
for i=1:n
    sortedevecs[:,i] = evecs[:,sortedindex[i]];
end

evecs[:,:] = sortedevecs[:,:]

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a non-mutating function in this case:

```
function sorteigen(evals::Vector{T},evecs::Matrix{T}) where {T<:Real}
    p = sortperm(evals)
    evals[p], evecs[:, p]
end
```

If you really need to save memory then you can do something like this that operates in-place:

```
function sorteigen!(evals::Vector{T},evecs::Matrix{T}) where {T<:Real}
    p = sortperm(evals)
    s = similar(evals)
    for i in axes(evecs, 1)
        for (j, pv) in enumerate(p)
            @inbounds s[pv] = evecs[i, j]
        end
        for j in eachindex(s)
            @inbounds evecs[i, j] = s[j]
        end
    end
    sort!(evals), evecs
end
```

It will be more memory efficient, but probably slower, because we operate row-wise so SIMD cannot be applied.

Also note that I use `Real` in the signature of the methods because general `Number` does not have to have an order defined (in particular complex numbers).